# Using $PROJECT_DIR$ in the path String in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a simple question, but I can't find the answer anywhere. I would like to use `$PROJECT_DIR$`default path variable in IntelliJ.

I wanted to add an icon to the Stage:

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("$PROJECT_DIR$/src/main/resources/com/example/demo/money.png"));
```

But this doesn't work, unfortunately :(

I tried also using `PROJECT_DIR` or `MODULE_DIR` or `$MODULE_DIR$`, but nothing works. Maybe it's impossible to use those path variables in such way (?). Please, explain it to me.

Using Absolute Path to the image works, but I would like to share my project and that's why I decided to replace it with a path variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use directory like this one. Intellij already know where is the project.

You have to check according to where will be located the file when it will be exported.

In you case, you have to use :

```java
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("com/example/demo/money.png"));
```

Because `resources` are already consider as resources and so will be in main folder in exported jar.

If it failed, you can try with less package, for example put `money.png` directly in the resource folder

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem.

Comment: Perfect ! Don't forget to accept my answer :)